# How to unit test device volume related methods in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, avaudiosession

I have a function in swift similar to -

```
func trigger() {
  var currentVolume = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume 
  if(currentVolume < THRESHOLD) { do_something() }
  else { fire_method() }
}
```

I want to write unit tests for `trigger` so that whenever I change the volume, `do_something` or `fire_method` is called depending on the `THRESHOLD`. `do_something` is basically triggering an api request and invoking a callback which needs to be tested.
Now the issue is, in simulator there is no way I can change the volume through code since `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume` is read-only variable. I'll have to use an iOS device for changing the volume but we can't run normal unit tests in a physical device.

I tried exploring libraries for mocking or stubbing the `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume`  but couldn't find appropriate solution. Tried `MPVolumeView()`, but by using it we can't run tests in simulator - it only works on a device. Also tried finding ways using which I can run tests on a physical device but couldn't get to a proper solution for this.

Comment: Maybe you need to use UI Tests.

Comment: Make your function testable by passing a volume value to `trigger`. You then call this from another function that gets the device volume. You don't need to test getting the device volume.  You just need to test acting on that volume.

Comment: the `trigger` function is triggered automatically through code - whenever there is change in the device volume. So I ideally wanted to test the entire scenario of this function being called on device volume change and subsequent events being fired